# Swagger UI doesn't render body parameter field for my complex type parameter in GET action of my Controller

Tags: asp.net, swagger, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.NET Web API 2 project to which I have added Swagger - Swashbuckle v5.6.0. Everything works fine. Swagger UI renders test endpoints for my API as expected.

I added a new Controller to my API. There is a `GET` action with a complex type parameter. For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body. This is the default behaviour.

**Here is my GET action:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<SearchModel>))]
    public IHttpActionResult Search(SearchModel searchOptions)
    {
        //....
        
        return Ok();
    }
```

**And her is my complex type:**

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
}
```

**The problem:**

But Swagger UI doesn't render body parameter field for my complex type in the `GET` action. For `POST` and `PUT` actions Swagger UI renders body parameter fields as expected but not for the complex type in my `GET` action.

[image: Screenshot of my GET action from Swagger UI]

As can be seen in the screenshot Swagger UI renders query parameters fields for attributes in my complex type instead of rendering a body parameter field for my type as it does in the case of `POST` and `PUT`.

My `GET` action is working fine when testing from Postman and filling the json in the body of the request. By setting breakpoint in the action inside Visual Studio I can see the values are bound to my object in the action parameter.

[image: Postman screenshot]

I have tried to decorate the parameter in my action with `[FromBody]` (which is the default for complex type) but same result.

Is this a bug in Swagger? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do what you want with Swagger. You can't send a request model in an HTTP GET method. You can however change the swagger UI to look like this:

[image: swagger GET with body]

but you won't be able to receive the model in your controller.

This is a known issue within the Swagger developers and it was discussed in 2016 and the final decision is that swagger won't support a request body in an HTTP GET method. [Here is the link to the already closed issue.](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2136)

You have three options here:

- Leave the method as it is, and test it in Postman, but not in Swagger.
- Follow the below steps to achieve the picture above, but please note, that it will only fix the UI part and you will always end up with `null` `SearchModel` in the controller when you press `Try it out!` in swagger.
- Make it a `[HttpPost` method instead of `[HttpGet]`.

---

How to make swagger UI display GET method with request body:

First, create one `Attribute` class:

```cs
public class ModelInBodyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ModelInBodyAttribute(string modelName, string description, bool isRequired)
    {
        this.ModelName = modelName;
        this.Description = description;
        this.IsRequired = IsRequired;
    }

    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can decorate your method in the controller:

```cs
[ModelInBody(modelName: nameof(SearchModel), description: "My model description", isRequired: true)]
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<SearchModel>))]
public IHttpActionResult Search(SearchModel searchOptions)
{
    //....

    return Ok(new List<SearchModel>());
}
```

After that create `IOperationFilter` class (`ModelInBodyOperationFilter`):

```cs
public class ModelInBodyOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var attribute = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<ModelInBodyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.parameters.Clear();
        operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
        {
            name = attribute.ModelName,
            description = attribute.Description,
            @in = "body",
            required = attribute.IsRequired,
            schema = new Schema { @ref = $"#/definitions/{attribute.ModelName}" }
        });
    }
}
```

Lastly, don't forget to register the `IOperationFilter` in `SwaggerConfig`:

```cs
c.OperationFilter<ModelInBodyOperationFilter>();
```

---

When you send the request via swagger, you will notice that the `Curl` part is absolutely correct, but still, in your controller there is nothing.
[image: curle example]

[image: example of GET method with a body in controller]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying to me that it's a Swagger issue and that they have decided not to support it. I find it strange though that Swagger (which is a tool) doesn't support it when it's supported by HTTP. Changing Swagger UI doesn't make sense when it doesn't mapped to the parameter in my action. I already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

There are endless discussions on whether you should have a PAYLOAD "Body content" in a GET request. As you mentioned **it's supported by HTTP** but you will find in the internet that many people suggest not to do it. I guess that swagger team also expect you not to use it.

Comment: Yes that's what's happening - swagger has its own opinion about it and doesn't render UI according to the underlying API, which Swagger is just a tool for and which does support it 

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late reply, but if you are able to decorate the controller with [APIController] , the swagger will display a different ui for the complex type.

[APIController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpJzo.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> The fact that request bodies on GET, HEAD, and DELETE are not interoperable has been clarified. (Sections 9.3.1, 9.3.2, and 9.3.5)

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#appendix-B.3-8

It's not recommended to include any type of request body or content on `GET`, `HEAD`, or `DELETE`.